# How can I use a fixed-minimum-length list in a total and elegant way?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm currently dealing with a function that goes like this:

```
foo = (\(a:b:c:d:e:f:_) -> foobar a b c d e f) . (++ repeat def)
```

In other words, given a list, it uses the first six elements for something, and if the list is less than six elements long, it uses `def` as a stand-in for the missing ones. This is total, but the pieces of it aren't (just like `map fromJust . filter isJust`), so I don't like it. I tried to rewrite this so that it doesn't need to use any partiality, and got this:

```
foo [] = foobar def def def def def def
foo [a] = foobar a def def def def def
foo [a,b] = foobar a b def def def def
foo [a,b,c] = foobar a b c def def def
foo [a,b,c,d] = foobar a b c d def def
foo [a,b,c,d,e] = foobar a b c d e def
foo (a:b:c:d:e:f:_) = foobar a b c d e f
```

I technically did what I want, but now this is a gigantic mess. How can I do this in a more elegant and less repetitive way?

Comment: Maybe, write an `uncons :: Default a => [a] -> (a,[a])` which defaults to `def`. Or a defaulting `takeWithDef`. And/or a view pattern / pattern synonym. This requires writing some auxiliary helper code, though.

Comment: @chi I think that's what I'll go with. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the totality argument for `case xs ++ repeat def of a:b:c:d:e:f:_ -> ...` is local enough that I wouldn't think twice about just using it and skipping all the extra machinery the existing answers are introducing. It is generally the more global totality arguments (which involve invariants maintained across multiple function calls, e.g.) that make me nervous.

Comment: Actually `takeWithDef` is not usable if it returns a regular list, since we need to pattern match that :-/ The proper solution is what Daniel wrote below in his second answer. `uncons` only gets the first element, so it's not that useful.

Answer (score 8):

Using the [safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) package, you can write, for example:

```
(!) = atDef def
foo xs = foobar (xs ! 0) (xs ! 1) (xs ! 2) (xs ! 3) (xs ! 4) (xs ! 5)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is at least shorter:

```
foo (a:b:c:d:e:f:_) = foobar a b c d e f
foo xs = foo (xs ++ repeat def)
```

You can easily see that the patterns are exhaustive, but now you have
to think a bit to see that it always terminates.  So I don't know if
you can consider it an improvement.

Otherwise we can do it with the state monad, although it's a bit
heavyweight:

```
foo = evalState (foobar <$> pop <*> pop <*> pop <*> pop <*> pop <*> pop)
  where
    pop = do xs <- get
             case xs of [] -> pure def
                        y:ys -> put ys >> pure y
```

I could also imagine using an infinite stream type like

```
data S a = S a (S a)
```

because then you could construct `foo` out of `repeat :: a -> S a`,
`prepend :: [a] -> S a -> S a`, and `take6 :: S a -> (a,a,a,a,a,a)`,
all of which could be total.  Probably not worth it if you don't
already have such a type handy.

Comment: Oh, I like the stream idea a lot. With an infix constructor like `data S a = a :- S a; infixr 5 :-` it looks quite clean; `foo xs = case prepend xs (repeat def) of a:-b:-c:-d:-e:-f:-_ -> foobar a b c d e f`.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun (and not recommended, this is for funsies), here's another way:

```
import Data.Default

data Cons f a = a :- f a
infixr 5 :-

data Nil a = Nil -- or use Proxy

class TakeDef f where takeDef :: Default a => [a] -> f a
instance TakeDef Nil where takeDef _ = Nil
instance TakeDef f => TakeDef (Cons f) where
    takeDef (x:xs) = x :- takeDef xs
    takeDef xs = def :- takeDef xs

foo xs = case takeDef xs of
    a:-b:-c:-d:-e:-f:-Nil -> foobar a b c d e f
```

The type that you use in the pattern match amounts to passing a type-level natural to `takeDef` saying how many elements to look at.

Comment: This is my preferred approach so far. I'd probably use a view pattern to complement it. (Why the "not recommended"? What are the cons?)

Comment: It embodies exactly what starts going wrong when you invest heavily in type-level programming: what was a one-line, instantly-understandable program balloons out into ten lines that require the reader to seriously engage their mental type-inference engine.

Comment: I see your point. I count `foo (takeDef -> a:-b:-c:-d:-e:-f:-Nil) -> foobar a b c d e f` as one line. I don't count the rest since it is code which should be in some library, for reuse. If it has to be written only for this case, it's clearly overkill as you say.